# Form action throws 'POST /mail.php Error (404): Not found'

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to send an email via html form with the help of php. However, it keeps 
throwing same error every time claiming it couldn't find php file. I've tried 
everything:

1. Installing NodeJs and running the code in localhost.
2. changing name="name" name="email" to something else.
3. Linking to another php script in case 
   something wrong with it.
4. Reading every SO page on this issue and trying every solution from there.

No luck at all.

Still `POST /mail.php Error (404): "Not found"`. What am I missing here?

Can you make it work on your system?

HTML:

```
<form name="contactform" method="POST" action="mail.php">
   <div>
      <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="name" required />
      <input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="email" required />
      <textarea type="text" name="comments" placeholder="message" required></textarea>
   </div>
      <button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];
$message = $_POST['comments'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "********@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Comment: Are HTML file and PHP file is the same folder?

Comment: @Pupil yes, they are in the same folder

Comment: I don't know why installing NodeJS would help you in this case..

Comment: "_Installing NodeJs and running the code in localhost_" Does that mean you're usually NOT running it via localhost? You do have a webserver running, don't you?

Comment: @kerbholz sorry for being such a noob. I thought it is worth mentioning. It is just my first time trying to link php to a form and I ran localhost only a couple of hours ago for the first time in my life...

Comment: Nothing wrong with being a noob, we've all been there. Just wanted to make sure you do have a web server running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :-

```
<form name="contactform" method="POST" action="mail.php">

  <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" placeholder="name" required />
  <input type="email" name="user_email" id="user_email" placeholder="email" required />
  <textarea type="text" name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="message" required></textarea>

  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="SEND" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please don’t post such “Use this: [code here]” answers without explaining _how_ what you have shown is supposed to fix the problem. (In this case, I can’t even see what that could possibly be though, your answer seems to be mere guess work rather than based on _anything_ related to the actual question.)

Comment: I have run the above code in one of my servers and its running fine and mail is also coming in my mail . Check the [link](http://janakalyantrust.in/sendmail.html) and this is the same code as above , means what I had modified for you .

Comment: I have received your mail , in my server I have put my mail to test .

Comment: @PHPWeb oh great! Does this mean my clients will be able to have this form working properly when site will be made eventhough I cannot make it work on my machine?

Comment: @PHPWeb thanx! I am glad it works at least on your server. Any wild guess why I cannot conquer this error?

Comment: Yes they can , just reload the sendmail.html page and check again , I have revert back your mail id .

Comment: Probably you are using your local machine that's why the mails were not fired .

Comment: @PHPWeb am using localhost:8080/myhtml.html and it throws error. So this is my problem then?

Comment: Yes , run it on a server , not from local machine .

Comment: @PHPWeb thanx a lot